# Simple if statement not working in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wrote a NodeJS app that uses eBay API to get listings from eBay. I'm having an issue where certain items are passing through even though they are supposed to be filtered out with a simple if statement.

The app receives post data from the front end as JSON, executes each search and then filters items out based on certain params. Here is the offending code:

```
if ( items[i].listingInfo.listingType != 'Auction' ) {
    //console.log( items[i].listingInfo.listingType );

    if ( items[i].primaryCategory.categoryId == '9355' ) {
        //console.log( items[i].primaryCategory.categoryId );

        if ( price < maxPrice && price > 40 ) {
            //console.log( price, maxPrice );
            file =  path + 
                    items[i].itemId + '-' + 
                    price + '-' + maxPrice + '-' + 
                    items[i].primaryCategory.categoryId + '-' + 
                    items[i].listingInfo.listingType;

            if ( !fs.existsSync( file ) ) {
                console.log(
                    'File ' + file + ' does not exist.', 
                    !fs.existsSync( file ), 
                    items[i].listingInfo.listingType, 
                    price < maxPrice,
                    items[i].itemId
                );

                fs.writeFile( file, ' ', function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        if (debug)
                            console.log('Writing ' + file + ' failed.');
                    }
                    else {
                        if (debug)
                            console.log('Writing ' + file + ' worked.');      
                        returnData.success = true;
                        returnData.results[ result.itemId ] = result;
                        console.log( price, maxPrice, !fs.existsSync( file ) );
                        console.log('success');
                    }
                })
            }
            else {
                returnData.discard.file[ result.itemId ] = result;
                delete returnData.results[ result.itemId ];
            }

        }
        else {
            returnData.discard.price[ result.itemId ] = result;
            if (debug)
                console.log('FAILED (price): ' + items[i].itemId + ' is ' + ( price - maxPrice ) + ' greater than maxPrice.');
        }
    }
    else {
        returnData.discard.cat[ result.itemId ] = result;
        if (debug)
            console.log('FAILED (categoryId): ' + items[i].itemId + ' is ' + items[i].primaryCategory.categoryId);
    }                    
}
else {
    returnData.discard.type[ result.itemId ] = result;
    if (debug)
        console.log('FAILED (listingType): ' + items[i].itemId + ' is a ' + items[i].listingInfo.listingType);                
}
```

You can see this line `if ( price < maxPrice && price > 40 )` should filter out any items that are greater than the maxPrice and lower than 40. However, it does not do this. I have no idea why it's happening and what is going on here. It seems very simple and straightforward but isn't. Here is the returned object where you can see that it's not working properly.

```
111004318957:
    listingType: "FixedPrice"
    maxPrice: 170
    price: 349
```

I'm also using node clusters, so my server.js file has this:

```
    function start(route, handle) {
        if ( cluster.isMaster ) {

            for ( var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++ ) {
                cluster.fork();
            }

            cluster.on('exit', function( worker, code, signal) {
                console.log( 'worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died' );
            })
        }
        else {
            function onRequest(request, response) {
                var postData = "";
                var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;

                request.setEncoding("utf8");
                request.addListener("data", function(postDataChunk) {
                    postData += postDataChunk;
                });
                request.addListener("end", function() {
                    //console.log('Request ended.');
                    if ( postData != '' ) {
                        postData = JSON.parse(postData);
                    }
                    //console.log(postData.search.searches[0]);
                    route(handle, pathname, response, postData);
                });
            }
            http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
            console.log("Server has started.");
        }
    }
```

Any help here is appreciated, thanks.

**EDIT:** I should have explained that the `111004318957` is the itemId that is returned by eBay. The result object looks like this:

```
results: {
    itemId1: {
        listingType: '',
        maxPrice: '',
        price: ''
    },
    itemId2: {
        listingType: '',
        maxPrice: '',
        price: ''
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:** `price` is set before this code snippet. It's returned in eBay's response and it's location is dependent on items[i].listingInfo.listingType, so there's a simple if/else to set that.

```
if ( items[i].listingInfo.listingType == 'AuctionWithBIN' ) {
    price = parseInt( items[i].listingInfo.buyItNowPrice.USD );
}
else {
    price = parseInt( items[i].sellingStatus.currentPrice.USD );
}
```

Comment: Put in an edit to explain.

Comment: Where are you setting the variable `price`?

Comment: @robertc I commented on Alex Smith's answer about that.

Comment: OK, let me put it another way: please show the code you are using to set the variable `price`.  Since it's the comparison involving this variable that seems to be the crux of the whole issue, and since you've posted a whole lot of other code which doesn't appear to be relevant, it's surprising to me that you've left out this crucial bit and don't seem to think it's important.

Comment: Haha, okay. Sorry about the misunderstanding. I made the edit and comment when I was half awake.

Comment: It looks to me from the API docs that you should be using `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`.  If you do want to use `parseInt` make sure you specify a radix of 10 to avoid any weird issues with leading zeros triggering octal parsing.

Answer (score 0):

JSON returns listingType, maxPrice, price.

Try `if (items[i].price < maxPrice && items[i].price > 40)`

Comment: price is set before. It's returned in the response from eBay and is in  different places depending on listingType.

Answer (score 0):

The author will almost certainly not be able to contribute anything to this question, to clarify if my statement is true or not, as it was asked six years ago.

However, it is fairly certain that the problem has to do with the following part of the code:

```
fs.writeFile( file, ' ', function(err) {
  if (err) {
    if (debug)
      console.log('Writing ' + file + ' failed.');
  }
  else {
    if (debug)
      console.log('Writing ' + file + ' worked.');      
    returnData.success = true;
    returnData.results[ result.itemId ] = result;
    console.log( price, maxPrice, !fs.existsSync( file ) );
    console.log('success');
  }
})
```

`fs.writeFile` is async, and if the OP is looping over a list of results, then the `result` in `returnData.results[ result.itemId ] = result` will always refer to the last element that loop, no matter if that element matches the condition `if ( price < maxPrice && price > 40 ) {` or not.